# TypeError - float object not callable

Tags: python

When I call the function:

```
def dif(a,b,c,g):
     y = float((3*a)*(g**2)+(2*b)*g + c)
     return y
```

I get the error :

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

when

```
a = 1
b = 3
c = -3
d = -1
g = 2.33333333
```

I dont seen to get an error when i write the code outside of the function, is it something to do with calling the function then?

Comment: Probably you re-assigned `float` name to a number.

Comment: To check if the name was re-assigned, check type(float) -- on 2.7 I get "<type 'type'>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You bound `float` to a floating point number, *masking* the built-in function:

```
>>> def dif(a,b,c,g):
...      y = float((3*a)*(g**2)+(2*b)*g + c)
...      return y
... 
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 3
>>> c = -3
>>> d = -1
>>> g = 2.33333333
>>> dif(a, b, c, g)
27.333333266666664
>>> float = 4.0
>>> dif(a, b, c, g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in dif
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Note the `float = 4.0` line.

Fix this by *not* assigning to `float`; you can 'fix' this by deleting the name so Python can fall back to the built-in:

```
>>> del float
>>> dif(a, b, c, g)
27.333333266666664
```